# Importar funcion con parámetro en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

En el archivo principal `app.js` estoy importando el archivo fabrica así:

> var ror2 = require('./node_modules/node-svm/sample/fabrica');

y lo uso así:

```
app.post('/servidor', function(req,res){

console.log(req.body.fact);//muestra bien el arreglo 
ror2.fabricar(req.body.fact);//envio el array 

});
```

Ese archivo tiene mi función que pasa de array a Map

```
    var fabricar=function(obj){
// const obj = [{id: 'a', time: 1}, {id: 'a', time: 2}, {id: 'b', time: 1}];
console.log(obj);// muestra el array que mando
const objMapped = obj.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let { id, time } = item;
  acc[id] = acc[id] || [];
  acc[id].push(time);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(objMapped);
}

exports.fabricar=fabricar;
```

Quiero importar la función fabricar

Comment: @devconcept como pasar el objMapped al archivo app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`module.exports` es uno de los *pseudo-global built-in identifiers* o identificadores seudo-globales incorporados de node.js que te permite definir y exportar cualquier trozo de código que quieras reutilizar en tu aplicación. Para hacer uso de un módulo se usa `require`, el cual básicamente se encarga de leer el código que hayas definido en tu módulo, ejecutarlo y retornar la propiedad `exports` del objeto `module`.

Bien, teniendo en cuenta esto, ya podemos entender por qué tu código no funciona:

Si declaras el siguiente módulo llamado *myModule.js*:

```
module.exports.logSomething = function(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

y lo intentas llamar desde *main.js* de la siguiente manera:

```
const logSomething = require('./myModule.js');
logSomething('hello');
```

Saltará un error debido a que *logSomething* en realidad no es una función, sino un objeto.

Por lo tanto tienes tres opciones:

Primero, asignar la función directamente a `module.exports`:

```
// myModule.js:
module.exports = function(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}

// main.js:
const logSomething = require('./myModule.js');
logSomething('hello');
```

Segundo, asignar la función como una propiedad de `exports` y al momento de importar en otro archivo solamente importar dicha función:

```
// myModule.js:
module.exports.logSomething = function(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}

// main.js:
const logSomething = require('./myModule.js').logSomething;
logSomething('hello');
```

Tercero, importar el módulo completo y llamar la función que se necesite:

```
// myModule.js:
module.exports = {
  logSomething: function(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
  },

  doSomethingElse: function(nonsense) {
    console.log(nonsense);
  }
}

// main.js:
const myModule = require('./myModule.js');
myModule.logSomething('hello');
myModule.doSomethingElse('something else');
```

Y listo. Programar es maravilloso.

Comment: pero llega el array a la funcion, pero no termina, no se porque, me explico mejor, mando desde main.js un array (req.body.fact) asi: "ror2.fabricar(req.body.fact);" y en myModule.js lo muestra el array enviado pero no termina la funcion " var fabricar=function(obj){ // const obj = [{id: 'a', time: 1}, {id: 'a', time: 2}, {id: 'b', time: 1}]; console.log(obj);// muestra el array que mando"

Comment: Y como haces para asegurarte de que en realidad tu función NO está terminando? Porque acabo de simular lo que intentas hacer en tu código y funciona perfectamente. Intenta hacer un return del objeto cuando la función haya terminado, almacena el resultado en main.js y has algo con ese objeto para asegurarte de que si está haciendo lo que debería hacer.

Comment: cuando lo mando un array estatico por ejemplo asi:
Código:
ror2.fabricar([{"id":65,"time":98},{"id":83,"time":170}]); funciona al 100%, pero cuando le mando asi: ror2.fabricar(req.body.fact); no funciona!!!, siendo var key_cadaTecla= [];  esto req.body.fact

Comment: No entendí lo ultimo, pero ha de ser problema del formato en el que llega req.body.fact, el cual debe ser un array de objetos, los cuales a su vez deben tener unas propiedades llamadas id y time en el mejor de los casos. En el peor de los casos la función te devolvería un array vacío o con clave y valor en 'undefined', de hecho, la única forma de que literalmente falle es que el objeto no sea un array, debido que 'reduce' es un método solo para arrays.

Comment: encontre el error, no estoy enviando array. me explico, lo estoy pasando desde ajax asi:data: { fact: JSON.stringify(key_cadaTecla)}, y ahi deja de ser array se convierte .json, mi pregunta es como convertirlo en array?, modificando, lo solucione asi var json = '{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4"}';

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

var arr = [];

for(var x in parsed){
  arr.push(parsed[x]);
}

Comment: Excelente. Solo hay que rastrear los resultados hasta encontrar el error :)

Answer (score 1):

Estaba equivocado respecto al problema de importar una función con parámetros en [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs).

En realidad, el problema fue el pasaje de parámetros en el codigo:

```
ror2.fabricar([{"id":65,"time":98},{"id":83,"time":170}]);
```

cuando enviaba un array estático funcionaba, pero cuando lo enviaba el array desde ajax asi:

```
data: { fact: JSON.stringify(key_cadaTecla)}
```

no funcionaba porque no estaba enviando un array sino un .json.

Para solucionarlo tuve que convertir el json a array asi:

```
var json = '{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4"}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
var arr = [];
for (var x in parsed) {
    arr.push(parsed);
}
```

y funciono!!!